# Windows HardDisk Activity

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-activity

System 4 PID continuously reads from and writes to my disk. I can't disable it.

Disabled Windows Update, Windows Antivirus, Windows Search.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: The system process is the windows kernel and the host for every single *device driver* (not program) you have installed.  Are you having a problem that you are trying to solve or is it just bothering you that your disk is being accessed?

Comment: stop downloading copyrighted torrents and I bet your disk activity will magically cease

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update is very well managed and does not kill disk or CPU in a properly functioning machine.

Windows Indexing takes lower priority and does not cause an issue (although it may run for a day or two depending on the size of your index.

Re-enable Anti Virus (never disable this) and do a full scan with your Anti Virus.  If this is Windows 10, look at the Windows Defender Threat settings and do an Offline Scan as well.

Try to get rid of any viruses you have that are activity network and disk activity.

You may need to restart in Safe Mode with Networking to set Windows Defender.

Also make sure any downloads in browsers have been stopped